# Error installing Curl, Curb Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to install Curb Gem on Ruby and I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Sites>gem install curb -- -- --with-curl-lib=C:\curl-7.34-devel-mingw32\bin -
-with-curl-include=C:\curl-7.34.0-devel-mingw32\include
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb -- --with-curl-lib=C
 :\curl-7.34-devel-mingw32\bin --with-curl-include=C:\curl-7.34.0-devel-mingw32\i
nclude
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:23:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/curb-0.8.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.
5/ext/gem_make.out

C:\Sites>
```

I've installed like everything anyone has said to install and I'm really lost :( I really just want this to work...I'm on windows 7 x64 but my ruby installation is 32bit( I find it works better for me for some reason to only use 32 bit ruby stuff)...

Right now I'm installing MinGW stuff I'm not even sure what the flipper to download in it, I just installed everything in the basic installation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu, I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Try installing those libraries and their dependencies.

Comment: Oh no this error was on Windows 7 or 8 I don't remember, I went to Ubuntu it seems Ruby isn't meant for Windows since no one knows the answer on Windows

Comment: This solution works in Windows 10 with WSL 2 (Ubuntu 18) too.